# Is there a way to create a procedure that fires whenever a new row is added to a table?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I know there are such things as stored procedures in SQL but is there a way to some how automate them in such a way that when a row is added to a table, sql azure automatically takes some of that data and adds it to a separate table?

For example,
Table "DocumentComments"
recieves a new row like so

```
CommentID: 23 UserID: 57 Comment:"This is a comment." InResponseToUser: 73
```

Execute Stored Procedure

```
Catch CommentID 23 and insert new notification in table "Notifications"
NotificationID : 2520 UserID: 73 Read: False
```

Comment: don't know much about azure, but in a standard SQL database, you're talking about triggers - actions that are performed automatically in response to activities on the tables the triggers are attached to.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Now I know exactly what to look up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Azure calls them triggers - here is a link to describe how to create the trigger: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336242.aspx

Here is an example from right here on StackOverflow:
[SQL Server input trigger to azure trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343127/sql-server-input-trigger-to-azure-trigger)

I hope this helps.